# Suggestion for a small OSS .NET project for study

Tags: .net, open-source

If one wants to learn better programming practices by studying a small .NET OSS project, what would that project be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/). It creates UML class diagrams and is not too complex. NClass uses .NET Framework 2.0 so you can focus on base "features" only. There is not so much documentation but the code is clean and easy. Furthermore it considers the requirements for the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications) so this app can run on various platforms, too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will have a look at it.

Comment: I also came across this http://filehelpers.com/ which i found interesting too...!

Answer (score 0):

[Sharp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) would be a great choice.  They are codifying best practices and design patterns for .NET ASP.NET MVC apps that include an ORM (NHibernate with support for EF4 coming soon).  They also use DI for their dependencies.  A good example of modern coding practices put into use.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com/), you will find pleanty of such projects for your study.